# SQL Server get all the records including null values if the parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
VenueCity = ISNULL(@VenueCity,VenueCity)
```

This statement returns all the values of VenueCity excluding its null values if the parameter @VenueCity is null. How can I get all the values including null for the field VenueCity if parameter @VenueCity is null ?

Comment: Make sure you read [Dynamic Search Conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html), your code is likely killing the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
ISNULL(VenueCity, '')=ISNULL(@VenueCity, ISNULL(VenueCity, ''))
```

OR

```
ISNULL(VenueCity, '')=case when ISNULL(@VenueCity,'')='' then ISNULL(VenueCity, '') else @VenueCity end
```